# What's the infinitive stem?

Tags: words, infinitive, stems

What's the infinitive stem? Can you explain it giving examples please?
 And is there something that called "resulting stem"?

Comment: It's a term of art used in describing Russian, Finnish and other languages; people can say such things about English. Usually it means "take the infinitive and chop something off", but it isn't a general linguistic term.

Comment: I am trying to learn Italian. The book learns it in English.I couldn't understand.Thanks for answer.

Comment: "Infinitive stem" is a term invented by grammarians to apply to a particular construction in a particular language; it's not something that every language is equipped with. In Latin (and probably in Italian) the infinitive stem would be the infinitive form with the final _-r_ or _-re_ chopped off. Some stems will end in consonants, and others in characteristic ("thematic") vowels.